# How can I stop some calendar entries from disappearing

Tags: google-calendar

For some reason. most of the appointments I make for my massage therapist, disappear. But only if I  make them at the clinic.

When I am there, I enter the next appointment.I then check to see if it is in the calendar. And it always is. However, every one of them (except once) disappear a few days later.

I am not deleting them. even accidentally because all other entries are always good.

Is there a way I  can stop this from happening?

Note - the mobile reception there is dicey.  I have Samsung **Note 20** and **Business Calendar**

Comment: The question is tagged with [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar), but there's also [an app named "Business Calendar"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal), which one did you mean?

Comment: I was under the impression that Business Calendar is just an interface to Google Calendar.  And there was any other tag I could use,  While I am entering it on Business Calendar on my mobile, I am checking it on my desktop in Google Calendar.